# How to format the following JSON data using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

```
[
    {
        "name":"A",
        "month":"Apr",
        "value":1234
    },
    {
        "name":"A",
        "month":"May",
        "value":2345
    },

    {
        "name":"A",
        "month":"Jun",
        "value":3457
    },
    {
        "name":"A",
        "month":"Jul",
        "value":6754
    }
]
```

I want to group the above JSON structure like this using JavaScript or jQuery:

```
   [{
     "id":"A",
     "data":[
     ["Apr",1234],
     ["May",2345],
     ["Jun",3457],
     ["Jul",6754],
     ]
   }]
```

Comment: How about some `for` and `if`?

Comment: It is a matter of a loop.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1gxnxo2b/ here is the solution as said above using some for and if loops

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g0j1cL2m/  let me know if you want any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi how about using underscore.js for this, its pretty simple with that
You can group by with underscore and then use the final json with your HTML Template.

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, function(d){return d.name});
```

The live example here [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uQZ3n/)

Comment: i have tried your method....but it is not working.....i am using the json data given above...

Comment: jsfiddle.net/1gxnxo2b here is the solution as said above using some for and if loops